# Read object values from Observable

Tags: rx-java

Is there a way I can return user list from userObservable in the below code. Basically how to read object values of an Observable.

```
public List<User> getUserList(){
    Observable<Map<String, Object>> userDetailsObservable = getUserDetails(...);
    Observable<Map<String, Object>> userLikesObservable = getUserLikes(...);
    Observable<List<User>> userObservable = Observable.zip(userDetailsObservable,
            userLikesObservable, new Func2<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>, List<User>>() {
                public List<User> call(Map<String, Object> value1, Map<String, Object> value2) {
                    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
                    //Iterating both maps and composing user list here.
                    return userList;
                }
            });
    userObservable.subscribe(new Subscriber<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(List<User> userList) {
            System.out.println("Merged values " + userList);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("Sequence complete.");
        }
    });
    // Throws ClassCastException which is expected... How do I get the user list from userObservable
    List<User> userList = List<User> userObservable;

    return userList; //Fetch the user list from userObservable and return
}
```

Comment: put an extra second on formatting your post plz

Comment: @Sleiman what formatting is missing in my post? Also I haven't put a lot of code to format. I am seeking for some help here. As long as its understandable it's fine. So any help to my question is much appreciated.

Comment: no your question is not clear and this why you didn't get any answers. You have to respect people spending time reading this.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi thanks for the feedback, I will make sure I format it better.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the `userObservable`. You will then get a list of users emitted when the data becomes available.

```java
userObservable
    .subscribe(users -> {
        for (User user : users) {
            // Do what you want with user.
        }
    });
```

EDIT: To return the list you would need to use a [`toBlocking()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toBlocking()) call. Then you can use one of the [Blocking Observable Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Blocking-Observable-Operators) to get the desired effect. Most likely `first()` or `single()` will work for you.

```java
return userObservable
    .toBlocking()
    .first();
```

Comment: kjones, thanks for your help. Is there a way I can return user list from subscribe. If you are wondering why I am doing this. I have a scenario where, I am making 2 asynchronous rest API calls using 2 observables and merging responses using userObservable. So at the end I want list of users returned from my method.

Comment: @PPK - I've update the answer that will do what you're looking for.

Comment: Note that blocking observables can be discouraged: `BlockingObservable is a variety of Observable that provides blocking operators. It can be useful for testing and demo purposes, but is generally inappropriate for production applications (if you think you need to use a BlockingObservable this is usually a sign that you should rethink your design).` so maybe you have to rethink what you are doing, on a higher level...

Comment: @kjones, are you saying you need to `subscribe()` first and then do the `toBlocking()`? Or do the blocking only if you want something returned?

Comment: @Azurespot, `toBlocking()` and `subscribe()` are mutually exclusive. Use one or the other. Be careful with `toBlocking()` it could wait forever if you have an infinite observable.